# Xamarin Forms Validation. Aggregate the result from multiple control behaviors

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page which has 3-4 entry controls. I've created a behavior to validate these entries. I've also extended the entry class to have borders, border colour and border radius. So the Xaml is somethin like this

```
<controls:ExtendedEntry x:Name="emailaddressEntry"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            BorderColor="Black"
                                            HasBorder="True"
                                            IsEnabled="True"
                                            Placeholder="Email Address"
                                            Text="{Binding EmailAddress}">
                        <controls:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>
                            <v:EntryValidatorBehavior x:Name="EmailAddressValidator"
                                                      IsCheckEmail="True"
                                                      IsCheckEmpty="True" />
                        </controls:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>
                    </controls:ExtendedEntry>
```

Now the EntryValidator Behavior has an IsValid property which tells us if the control is in a valid state or not. What I want to do is enable or disable my submit button based on the IsValid of all the entries. Something like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding OnCreateCommand}" Text="Submit Account Application" BindingContext="{x:Reference EmailAddressValidator,PasswordValidator,AddressValidator}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EmailAddressValidator.IsValid && PasswordValidator.IsValid && AddressValidator.IsValid}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in your `Button` `<Button Command="{Binding OnCreateCommand}" Text="Submit Account Application" BindingContext="{x:Reference EmailAddressValidator,PasswordValidator,AddressValidator}"` but why not create a boolean in your PageModel which does it for you?

Bind your `ExtendedEntry` `IsValid` properties to booleans in your PageModel, i.e. `IsEmailValid`. And then in your PageModel a boolean `IsFormValid` to which your bind your button like this: `<Button Command="{Binding OnCreateCommand}" Text="Submit Account Application" IsEnabled="{Binding IsFormValid}" />`.

Also you need to implement the `IPropertyChanged` on your PageModel or use [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to make your life easier.

Comment: This was helpful!